# Accessing a widgets value in django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I need to do an ajax call in django depending on the values set on two date fields and a select dropdown. In order to do that I have to pass those values into javascript function which will be called when a button is click. I have set the form dates fields as Date type and select as Choice field. How can I pass the current values of these to the javascript function?

**form.html (template):**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">* Start Date:</label><br>
    {{ form.date1 }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">* End Date:</label><br>
    {{ form.date2 }}
</div><br><br>
<div class="form-group">
    Category: {{ form.category }}
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning"
onclick="javascript:check_availability({{ XXX }}, '{% url "find_available" %}');">
    Check Now
 </button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function check_availability(date1, date2, category, url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: {date1: date1, date2: date2, category: category},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: available_now,
        error: function() {
            alert('Unable to find available items')
        }
    });
}

fucntion available_now () {...}
```

**In form.py (view)**

```
category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(...))
date1 = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput())
date2 = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput())
```

How could I pass those three values set in the widgets in place of XXX for the above function call? I need to specifically get the selected value of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't in any way a question about Django, but about Javascript. Since you are using jQuery for your Ajax function, you should use it to get the value of the fields. Also note, you should avoid setting `onclick` handlers directly in the HTML; you should do that in your jQuery script as well.

```
<button type="button" id='find-available' class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-url='{% url "find_available" %}');">
    Check Now
 </button>

...

$('form').on('click', '#find-available', function() {
   $this = $(this);
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: $this.data('url'),
        data: $this.parent().serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: available_now,
        error: function() {
            alert('Unable to find available items')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not doing a full form submission here. The ajax call is used to check for available items to that will render as a list to the user. Therefore I need call the javascript function with partially filled data items date1, date2 and select option. How can I refer those values set to pass the function?

Comment: I didn't post anything about form submission. The data sent here will include those field values; if you really feel the need to restrict it to just those three, then get their values individually with `$('#id_date1').val()` etc. But that's lots more code, and I don't see why it matters.

Comment: I can set an id (#) value to the widget at the form.py. For this specific scenario I would like to avoid sending all data the server. Using the way you suggested will be OK. I was wondering is there a way to directly get the value in {{}} variable in the template. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No of course there's no way of getting the value with Django template tags, because the user hasn't entered the value at the time the Django tags are rendered. And there's no need to set an explicit ID; form fields get one automatically, as I show above.

Comment: Changed code does not calling the jquery function now. Here is the code. `<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" id="find-available"
                                    data-url='{% url "find_available" %}'>` In jquery `$('form').on.('click', '#find-available', function() {
    alert('You clicked me')});` //sample

Comment: There was an extra `.` after `on`, fixed.